# Specify a format for "asp-for" HTML Tag (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.1

In an ASP.NET Core project I have to display a (readonly) date in a specific format (say "dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM")

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Date" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="Date" readonly class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I do it, knowing that the `Date` field is declared in the model like this

```
public DateTime Date { get { return this.Timestamp.DateTime; } }
```

?

Answer (score 24):

Try this.

```
<input asp-for="Date" asp-format="{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}" readonly class="form-control" />
```

Comment: I realize this is 5 years later, but does this still work in ASP.NET Core 6? When I tried it, the input just displayed the literal format string instead of the value in the format.

Comment: I needed to add `type="text"` to override the default of `type="datetime-local"` which shows the browser's datetime picker meaning the format is ignored.

Answer (score 14):

Alternatively, you could decorate the property with `DisplayFormatAttribute`.

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM}")]
public DateTime Date { get { return this.Timestamp.DateTime; } }
```

The markup you have would not need to change.

Comment: I tried this and found it threw an error when the underlying datatype didnt conform to the DataFormatString pattern; i.e.with a format of {dd/MM/yyyy}, becuase my underlying data was a DateTime with HH:MM, I got an exception

Comment: @RichyRoo You received that error because MM is month, not minutes.

Answer (score 4):

If it is read only, you could hardcode as -

```
<input value="@Model.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")" readonly class="form-control" />
```

Or display as text

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Date" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10 form-control-static">
        @Model.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using ASP.Core TagHelpers as per your question;

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime Date { get { return this.Timestamp.DateTime; } }
```

will format the input fields nicely in accordance with your locale setting.
I haven't found a tag helper solution for any other tags, looks like hardcoding as per Win's answer